# Django admin listing not showing data correctly

Tags: python, django, django-1.5

I am creating a website using django, I have a table called articles, whenever I create any new record it is showing correctly in the database (Postgres) and in the details page of django admin, but in the listing it is being displayed as: Article object.
Any Idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the **unicode**() method in the Article model class.

For example:

```
class Article(models.Model):

    name = models.Charfield()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a [`__unicode__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode) method for your model.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
I forgot to add the below in my model:

```
def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```